# Javascript code in PHP variable?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to put a javascript code in PHP variable exactly like this:

```
$ch = '<script> var w = window.innerWidth; var h = window.innerHeight; var id = "'. $row['ch_id'] .'" ; document.write(<iframe width="'+w+'" height="'+h+'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" allowtransparency="true" src="http://www.exemple/embed.php?width='+w+'&height='+h+'&channel='+id+'&autoplay=true"></iframe>); </script>';
```

I give me this error:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant w - assumed 'w' in /test.php on line 9

Notice: Use of undefined constant h - assumed 'h' in /test.php on line 9

Notice: Use of undefined constant w - assumed 'w' in /test.php on line 9

Notice: Use of undefined constant h - assumed 'h' in /test.php on line 9

Notice: Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' in /test.php on line 9
```

Whats wrong on the code ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to escape your quotes. As a side note you should stop using `document.write`.

Comment: Also PHP uses `.` as the concantenation operator.

Comment: In this case @thatidiotguy the OP wants to preserve the JavaScript formatting in the script code, so the `+` is appropriate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is your Javascript:**

```
<script>
var w = window.innerWidth; 
var h = window.innerHeight; 
var id = 23;   // For example
document.write('<iframe width= height="'+h+'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" allowtransparency="true" src="http://www.exemple/embed.php?width="'+w+'"&height="'+h+'"&channel="'+id+'"&autoplay=true"></iframe>');
</script>
```

**This is when inside a PHP variable:**

```
$ch = '<script>
       var w = window.innerWidth; 
       var h = window.innerHeight; 
       var id = "'. $row['ch_id'] .'"; 
       document.write(\'<iframe width= height="\'+h+\'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" allowtransparency="true" src="http://www.exemple/embed.php?width="\'+w+\'"&height="\'+h+\'"&channel="\'+id+\'"&autoplay=true"></iframe>\');
       </script>';
```

**Demo:**
http://3v4l.org/fH0Vi

Comment: yes the problem was the quotes .. thanks man for your help

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to escape the ' try this:

```
$ch = '<script> var w = window.innerWidth; var h = window.innerHeight; var id = "'. $row['ch_id'] .'" ; document.write(\'<iframe width="\'+w+\'" height="\'+h+\'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" allowtransparency="true" src="http://www.exemple/embed.php?width=\'+w+\'&height=\'+h+\'&channel='.$row['chd_id'].'&autoplay=true"></iframe>\'); </script>';
```

I hope the ' are all in their places now :)

Comment: `w`, and `h` are JavaScript variables declared within the `<script>` block...

Comment: Ok, I have edited the string, now I guess it is right :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$ch = "<script> var w = window.innerWidth; var h = window.innerHeight; var id = '". $row['ch_id'] ."' ; document.write(<iframe width="\'+w+\'" height="\'+h+\'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" allowtransparency="true" src= \"http://www.exemple/embed.php?width='".$w."'&height='".$h."'&channel='".$row['chd_id']."'&autoplay=true\"></iframe>); </script>";
```

Comment: I just made a change. Try it now

Comment: Why have you converted JavaScript variables to PHP variables? That will not work.

Comment: `<iframe width="\'+w+\'" height="\'+h+\'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" allowtransparency="true"...` - You didn't properly escape the double quotes. If you're using double quotes within a string denoted by double quotes, you need to escape them using `\"`. Also, `$w` and `$h` are not PHP variables, they're JavaScript variables...